# SQL UPDATE table with more than 1 word fail

Tags: php, sql

my table "list_article_groups have several groups which is the same, but have different spellings and small differences that cause duplicates in system. So I want to join (seach and replace) all the duplicates.

I am running this expression;

```
UPDATE `list_articles_groups`
SET `name` = replace(name, '%front%cable%', 'Front cable')
```

But I get 0 result. If I replace % with space, i get 1000 results. Any clues?

Comment: what is our sql plateform?

Comment: Without sample data and desired results, this question is too open-ended.  What do *you* mean by "same, but different"?

Comment: @zip Platform is, phpmyadmin- PHP version: 7.0.33

Comment: @GordonLinoff, so all articles with same "name" will be listed in same groups. But over time users have written same names in several ways, such as "front cable brake" and another one is "front cable brakes" which now puts them in different groups. Instead of seach and replace all strings one by one, I try to use the % to cover more at same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Using "where".

UPDATE `list_articles_groups` 
SET `name` = 'Front Cable' WHERE `name` LIKE '%front%cable%'

Answer (score 0):

Run this, ltrim and ltrim work with most sql plateforms. What is yours and we can adjust the code below

for sql server

```
UPDATE list_articles_groups
SET name = 'Front cable' where name like '%' + 'front' + '%'+ 'cable' + '%'
```

for postgres

```
UPDATE list_articles_groups
SET name = 'Front cable' where name like '%' || 'front' || '%'|| 'cable' || '%'.
```

You get the idea.

Comment: `where name like '%' || name || '%'` what is this? Do you know the meaning of this condition? This will update all the rows of the table.